# How to save an SQL file using Save Dialog in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an SQL file using Application.Path & SQL_statements.After that I write SQL statements into this file through vba.Now I want to save the file after all SQL statements are generated in an different directory.This directory depends upon the user.Hence I want to give him an Save as Dialog .

Thus, I need to save the file that I created through vba, and save it using save as dialog in a location specified by the user and delete the copy of file created by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want Application.GetSaveAsFilename.  Here's an example.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim sSql As String

    sFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "*.txt,*.txt", , "Save SQL File")

    If sFile <> "False" Then
        sSql = "Select * from abc"
        lFile = FreeFile
        Open sFile For Append As lFile
        Print #lFile, sSql
        Close lFile
    End If

End Sub
```

sFile will be a string that is the full path and name.  I don't know what a "SQL file" is, so I guessed it was a file with a sql extension.  sFile will be "False" if the user clicks Cancel on the dialog.

To copy the file after it's been created

```
Sub TestCopy()

    Dim sNewFile As String, sOldFile As String
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim sSql As String

    sNewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "*.txt,*.txt", , "Save SQL File")

    If sNewFile <> "False" Then
        sSql = "Select * from abc"
        sOldFile = "C:\Book1.txt"
        lFile = FreeFile
        Open sOldFile For Append As lFile
        Print #lFile, sSql
        Close lFile
        FileCopy sOldFile, sNewFile
    End If

End Sub
```

You'll end up with two files - one at C:\Book1.txt and one where the user chooses.

Comment: How to save my file.I'm a newbie to vba.Don't know a lot of things in it which might be ordinary

Comment: What kind of file is it?  Excel file? Text file?  How are you creating it?

Comment: It's  textfile.I'm creating it like this.

Comment: Dim filename As Variant

filename = Application.Path & "\" & "Book1.txt"

Dim sql As String

Dim My_filenumber As Integer
sql = "Select * from abc"
My_filenumber = FreeFile

Open filename For Append As #My_filenumber

Print #My_filenumber, sql

Close #My_filenumber

Comment: after this I want to save this file through a dialog

Comment: I've edited the code to show one way to do it.  See if that does what you need.

Comment: Ur code works fine.Just a sidetrack question.What if I already created my file and now want to copy this file where the user wants.